# Do I need the hyphen?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, compound-adjectives

"Part-Time" in the beginning of this sentence is technically a compound adjective to employment, but it is separated by "or temporary." Do I still hyphenate "part-time"? The same question holds for "full-time."

*Employees who transition from part-time or temporary employment to full-time, regular employment..."*

Comment: The key thing to note in that sentence, despite the separation of the words, is *part-time employment* and *full-time employment*, which is the standard punctuation of the compound adjectives. That there are multiple adjectives doesn't change how you would punctuate the individual adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would. Hyphenation of compound adjectives can be a style question as much as grammar. Some style guides prescribe specific words that don't need hyphens, or can be combined as one word. Check AP or another guide for examples.

In both sentences, the noun is separated from the compound adjective (by "regular" in the second case). If you believe in hyphenating part-time and full-time as adjectives, the separation doesn't change the grammatical function.